# PHP : Optimal way to display user the selected options from the dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of cities in database. I want to display user, the selected source and destinations (in case he has already selected earlier) in two dropdowns,one for source and other for destination, on the edit page.

The Table Schema

**User Table**

```
-----------------------------
UID     |  RouteID
-----------------------------
        |
        |
```

**Route Table**

```
-----------------------------
ID | From_city  |  To_city
-----------------------------
   |            |
   |            |
```

The obvious way is :

1) Fire one query to get the user's selected source and destination city.
2) Fire another query to get distinct source cities and select the user's selected source city.
3) Fire third query to get distinct destination cities and select the user's selected destination city.

It costs me three queries.

Can I further optimize this process. The main objective here is that when the user doesn't select either on the edit page, the old selected values get submitted through the form.

**EDIT**

1. Source and Destination list can be different.
2. On Edit Page, user selects from where he want to go where. In case, he chose that already and he still comes to page, I show the earlier selected choice by choosing the them in the dropdown as defaults. This is because in case he comes to Edit page, does nothing and submits the form, I will still be updating the earlier choice.

Comment: list of source cities and list of destination cities are different ones?

Comment: "The main objective here is that when the user doesn't select either on the edit page, the old selected values get submitted through the form" - I don't understand it. You didn't say anything about the edit page. Please, explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by two queries.

1. Fetch cities.
2. Fetch user data with `JOIN` statement.
3. When building city list in your view, inside `foreach` loop:

   ```
   foreach ($cities as $city){
     if($city->id_city == $user_data->from_city){
       echo '<option val="'.$city->id_city.'" selected="selected">..</option>'
     } else {
       echo '<option val="'.$city->id_city.'">..</option>'
     }
   }
   ```

Do same for `to_city`.